# In Web Site, could not load type

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, vs-web-site-project

There is already a question in stackoverflow where there is an error for a web application the compiler cannot find the load type.

This is not like that at all.  This is a Web Site and the problem is in the building of the code when it looks for namespaces and definitions that already exist in the code.
[image]

This compilation error points to the first line of .master file and refers to an "Inherits" assignment.
[image]

The code behind only shows a warning, not an error.  Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your master page declaration should look like (presuming all files on same level in directory):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Admin.master.cs"
    Inherits="Applications" %>
```

Your code-behind declaration should look like this:

```
public partial class Site : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ...
}
```

If you were using VS, then it should have done this automatically for you. Are you sure this is not a Web Application project template?

In any case, your page code-behind should be inheriting from the page type; in your case, you are inheriting from a user control (master page is a user control).